# как задать часовой пояс?

Tags: java

Просьба добавить сюда пару символов, чтобы выводить не лондонское время, а московское, то есть +3 к часовому поясу Лондона.... гуглить упоролся

```
   // Текущее время
    Date currentDate = new Date();
    // Форматирование времени как "день.месяц.год"
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
    String dateText = dateFormat.format(currentDate);
    // Форматирование времени как "часы:минуты:секунды"
    DateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());
    String timeText = timeFormat.format(currentDate);
    textViewDate.setText(dateText);
    textViewTime.setText(timeText);`
```

Answer (score 0):

Пока ждал ответа, гугл сдался и выдал его.
Перед моим кодом нужно дописать одну строку:

```
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Moscow"));
```

Так же заинтересовало, как программно определить тайм-зону пользователя? Наверняка ее можно вытащить из настроек его телефона?